# GCM push fails with NotRegistered

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use **GCM**(**G**oogle **C**loud **M**essaging).

I am able to receive a token.

I go try to push a message right away got response :

`"success":1`,

It never reaches my app.

Next time I push it, I get a failure with

`"error":"NotRegistered"`.

From my understanding reading posts about it, my token seems to get removed from gcm server.(if I understand correctly)

Has anyone been through this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your token saved properly at the server? Did you log it in your app and compare with the one in the db?

Comment: I think your Client site is working fine. check it on server.

Comment: At this moment, I am not storing the tokens on my server. I am testing the minimum to get it to work. I copy the token I receive to the clipboard and then paste it in a simple script to send that push.

Comment: Could be an issue with your client side listener service and how you declared it in the manifest. Could you try the quickstart [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)?

Comment: @Koh I found out that this was exactly the issue I had. I had missed the BroadcastReceiver in manifest. Thanks.

Comment: I am using GCM over the web (briwser based notifications) and have started getting this same message recently when sending some notifications (not all). Where is this registration ID that people are talking about?  I am getting this message: `{"multicast_id":63135.....,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]`  and all my manifest file looks like is: `{"gcm_sender_id": "10395...." }`