# GCM IOS NotRegistered issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've been using GCM just fine for a long time already. One day it suddenly broke. The problem is that the first push I send I get success status back but the app doesn't receive any push whatsoever. The second push I send gets failure with an NotRegistered error. I reinstall the app: success(no notification received), failure(NotRegistered) -> Loop. I don't know what's changed. Google support is being very unhelpful and is taking a lot of time answering simple question whether it is GCM problem, APNs problem or client problem. If anyone had such issue before, please let me know what to look for. That is how it looks like:

[image: Here is the HTTP log]

I suspect that it happened after updating to iOS 9. I'm not sure though. If there are things in new iOS that might be blocking GCM I would appreciate if somebody pointed it out.

**UPDATE:**

[GCM push fails with NotRegistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835653/gcm-push-fails-with-notregistered)

that guy had a similar problem. The issue was with some manifest file. Could there be some entries in the Info.plist that I need to add for iOS 9 to allow GCM ?

**UPDATE:**

onTokenRefresh is being called every time the app launches. I'm getting the same token back, though. So there is a problem with a token on a GCM server, I suspect.

**GCM DELEGATE CODE IN APPDELEGATE:**

```
var connectedToGCM = false


private var deviceToken: NSData?

var gcmSenderID: String!
let authorizedEntity = "my GCM Sender_ID"


public func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Register for remote notifications
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        // Fallback
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

    // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
    // [START start_gcm_service]
    let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)

    return true
}

public func onTokenRefresh() {
    print("Token needs to be refreshed!")
    let options = [
        kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption : deviceToken!,
        kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption : true
    ]
           GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(authorizedEntity, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: options) { (token, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Token: \(token)")
        }
    }
}


public func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

public func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
    // token to enable reception of notifications
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
    self.deviceToken = deviceToken
}

public func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
    connectedToGCM = false
}

public func applicationDidBecomeActive( application: UIApplication) {
    print("App became active")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
    GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({
        (NSError error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.connectedToGCM = true
            print("Connected to GCM")
            // ...
        }
    })
}

public func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
    GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

public func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error registering")
}

public func application( application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        print("Notification received(background): \(userInfo)")

        NotificationManager.sharedInsteance().parseNotification(userInfo)

        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

**UPDATE**

OK, so I believe I messed up with .plist location (it wasn't in the root for some reason). I moved to the root and now I'm getting this warning/error when starting GCM:

UPD.
Okay, it actually happened only once and stopped. So I don't think the problem is here.

After I moved .plist to the root directory onTokenRefresh() calls stopped, but I'm still getting NotRegistered.

[image: Error]

Comment: Could you include the callbacks you implement in your application delegate for GCM?

Comment: This usually happens with an invalid APNs token. Are you sure the APNS token you're using to register with GCM is valid for the particular server. For instance you're not using a Sandbox APNS token to send messages to your app signed with PROD certificate. Also make sure you're correctly assigning value to `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` when registering with GCM.

Comment: I'm using the right sandbox option. How do I check if the token is invalid ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I solved the problem. It appeared that I was not using the right iOS Development Provisioning Profile. I was using a generic one, while I needed to use a specific one for my bundle name. The reason it happened was because I reinstalled my OS a week ago or so, so the other certificate was wiped out and didn't work until I downloaded and manually added it to Xcode. I also needed to delete the team provisioning profile from the device as well. Totally not GCM or APNs fault.

Comment: Happened to me and fixing the provisioning profile is what worked for me too.  I think it started happening after upgrading iOS and xcode, need to redownload my provisioning profile.

Comment: Really helpful! Thanks so much for asking and answering this question!