# Error:Not Registered - GCM Push Notification

Tags: php, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have done the GCM Integration in iOS client, and i am able to push a notification from DHC - REST client. When i tried my registration token in my backend php it says Error: Not Registered.

Please help me on this, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workarounds:

- Make sure that the APNS token you're using to register with GCM is valid for the particular server.
- Make sure that you are using the right iOS Development Provisioning Profile. Check if you're using the specific profile for your bundle name instead of a  a generic one. To get push and background notifications working again:

  - Remove/Uninstall the application from the test device.
  - Perform 'clean' in XCode.
  - Perform 'build' in XCode.
  - Reinstall the app to the device.

You can check these related SO questions:

- [GCM IOS NotRegistered issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296515/gcm-ios-notregistered-issue)
- [GCM push fails with NotRegistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835653/gcm-push-fails-with-notregistered)
- [gcm push notification: first success, then not registered in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852858/gcm-push-notification-first-success-then-not-registered-in-ios)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response..! It worked actually my user token was mistaken.. Now it worked..