# GCM Success then NotRegistered

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push to my app and testing using that website : http://www.pushwatch.com/gcm/

First try I receive a success message and then error message : NotRegistered.

Same result with that code :

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    id : <input type="text" name="id"/><br/>
    message : <input type="text" name="message"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer"/>
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $registrationIds = $_POST["id"];
    echo "CALL<br/>";
    echo "message = ".$message." / ids = ".$registrationIds."<br/><br/>";

    // API access key from Google API's Console
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIza....' );
    // prep the bundle
    $msg = array
            (
             'message'      => $message,
             'title'        => 'This is a title. title',
             'subtitle'     => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
             'tickerText'   => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
             'vibrate'      => 1,
             'sound'        => 1,
             'largeIcon'    => 'large_icon',
             'smallIcon'    => 'small_icon'
            );
    $fields = array
            (
             'to'   => $registrationIds,
             'data'                 => $msg
            );

    $headers = array
            (
             'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
             'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    echo "RESULT<br/>";
    echo $result;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following workarounds based from this [forum](http://www.simosh.com/article/dgjcaffe-errornot-registered-gcm-push-notification.html):

- Make sure that the APNS token you're using to register with GCM is valid for the particular server.
- Make sure that you are using the right iOS Development Provisioning Profile.
- Check if you're using the specific profile for your bundle name instead of a a generic one.
- To get push and background notifications working again:

  - Remove/Uninstall the application from the test device.
  - Perform 'clean' in XCode.
  - Perform 'build' in XCode.
  - Reinstall the app to the device.

Check these related SO questions:

- [gcm push notification: first success, then not registered in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852858/gcm-push-notification-first-success-then-not-registered-in-ios)
- [GCM IOS NotRegistered issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296515/gcm-ios-notregistered-issue)
- [GCM push fails with NotRegistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835653/gcm-push-fails-with-notregistered)